# Return error message from observer Magento

Tags: php, magento

I made a custom module for observer on customer save before event for both admin and front side

My config file

```
<global>
        <events>
            <customer_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <pavans_profile>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Pavans_Profile_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>customerSaveAfter</method>
                    </pavans_profile>
                </observers>
            </customer_save_before>

        </events>

    </global>
```

It calls my observer before customer data saved

```
class Pavans_Profile_Model_Observer {
    public function customerSaveAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) 
    { 
        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
        $controller->setFlag('', Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
        $response = array('error' => -1, 'message' => $helper->__('Error'));
        return $controller->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));    

    }
}
```

I want to pass error message on customer form and stop controller to save customer data, but above code shows me error message

```
Call to a member function setFlag() on a non-object
```

So i'm unable to get object of controller.

Answer (score 0):

You have error on

```
$controller->setFlag('', Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
```

if you are using setFlag than you need to written as below

```
  $controller->setFlag(Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
```

Below are the snippet of function

```
class Pavans_Profile_Model_Observer {
    public function customerSaveAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) 
    { 
        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();

        $response = array('error' => -1, 'message' => $helper->__('Error'));
        return $controller->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));    

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Pavans_Profile_Model_Observer {
    public function customerSaveAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) 
    { 
        $controller = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction();
        $controller->setFlag('', Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
        $response = array('error' => -1, 'message' => $helper->__('Error'));
        return  $controller->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));    

    }
}
```

I think you need to add getEvent() to your code line.I have placed modified code.

Comment: Its showing same error as before I'm using magento 1.8.1

Comment: Try this  $request = Mage::app()->getRequest();
$action = $request->getActionName();
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->setFlag($action, Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);